# How can I use GCC-7.1.0 on Windows?

Tags: c++, gcc

C++17 is coming out, and I'm hoping to use it in some upcoming projects. How can I install GCC-7.1.0 on windows without relying on Cygwin? I have a version of mingw already installed on my computer, and I've downloaded and unpacked the folder containing the source code for gcc-7.1.0. How can I use my current version of the gcc compiler to compile gcc-7.1.0? Is there a sequence of commands I can carry out in the windows command prompt to do this?

Comment: Compile it using a version of mingw-w64 you already have

Comment: google keyword: mingw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to install a recent GCC is to use the MinGW distribution provided by Stephan T. Lavavej at https://nuwen.net/mingw.html

He provides a download of precompiled-binaries as well his build script. So you can either download the current version or use his build scripts to compile your chosen version.